# over 5000 resource files gives "cannot resolve symbol R" error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I've found that if I have more than 5000 files in a resource directory (**raw** in my case) I get the dreaded "cannot resolve symbol R" error in Android Studio, where it won't resolve the project's R class.  It's fine when I have 5000 files, but if I add one more and do a gradle sync then I get the error (cue Mr. Creosote).

It's running on a Windows 10 box with 8g of heap and 512m of stack, and it builds just fine.  It's just that the IDE doesn't resolve R.  No errors from gradle or in idea.log.

Anyone seen this before and hopefully know how to get around it?

Comment: I had a similar issue, but it happened when I added xml layout files. What helped me as doing a project clean and rebuild. To do that in Android Studio go to Build -> Clean Project

Comment: I've cleaned, rebuilt, synced, invalidated caches, re-imported the project...nothing helps.  It's clearly a hard limit at 5000 files in the directory.